# mySQL combining two tables I get more results

Tags: mysql

I have one table of like this

user|itemID

and another table like this:

itemID | itemTrait1 | itemTrait2  etc...

I am trying to link the tables in one query which should be simple. I conduct the query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2  WHERE Table1.userID = 1 AND Table1.itemID = Table2.itemID;
```

The issue is that I am getting 456 results returned but if I simply run:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE userID = 1;
```

I get 434 results. Should both these statements get the same number of results returned?

How I imagine this call working is that for every entry in Table 1 for user 1 it connects it to the item's data in Table2? I think I am missing something here.

Comment: This would happen if there is more than one matching row for a itemid in table2. Lets say userID  1 has itemid 1 in table 1 and there are two rows for itemid1 in table2, then you have two rows for that user. It has to be a one-to-many relation. I can't see any other explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Query to combine both tables based in itemID

```
select * from table1 t1
left join table t2 on t1.itemID = t2.itemID
where t1.itemID = 1;
```

if you are getting the more records than the records that of *table1* then your second table *table2* must have multiple records for itemID. for example

Table1

```
user | itemId               
---------------
1    |  1
```

Table2

```
itemId  |   itemTrait1    | itemTrait2  
----------------------------------------
1       |      A          |  B
1       |      C          |  D
```

now when you will apply join here it will join itemID 1 with two items of second table.